# streaming of mms on android

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I would like to develop an android application and it plays live radio broadcasting by clicking on a button. I am using MediaPlayer to do this. It works well when I play audio file online, such as

```
"http://XXXXXXXXX.com/XXXX.mp3"
```

However, I would like to ask how can I stream the following link which is the radio broadcasting link from Hong Kong.

```
"http://202.177.192.111/radio1"
"mms://202.177.192.111/radio1"
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: it should be same as first URL..is it not?

Comment: Yes, they are the same channel. The first one can be played by putting the link in the browser while the second one should be opened by windows media player. Just wonder how an android application can open them

Comment: whats ur first URL..have u hit your Second url directly on Browser?

Comment: its not real window media player , its just a image on server..nothing to worry

Comment: the first link with .mp3 means that I can open online mp3 file. I can play the second one on browser. However, I would like to do this in an android application without opening browsers.

Comment: so whats the problem coming when you accesing second URL audio in your android based application..?